# How to order by using doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I used to get my data using this command so the first array is for find variable and the second array is for the order.
So I need to order with specific column:name of test(that is an object that has many columns: id/name ) But I dont know how !! when I enter _test.name I get unrecognized field

```
 ->findBy(
          array('_id'     => $id),
          array('_test'  =>'ASC')
          );

class model1
{
 
   
    private $_idModel1;
 
    /**
   *
   *      @ORM\ManyToOne()
   *      @ORM\JoinColumns({
   *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id1",
   *      referencedColumnName="id2")
   *      })
   */
    private $_test;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot order using a relation with the findBy, but you can do it creating a query builder:

```
$model1Repository->createQueryBuilder('model1')
       ->leftJoin('model1._test', 't')
       ->where('model1._id = :id')
       ->setParameter('id', $id)
       ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC');
```

The code has not been tested, you should adapt it to your code.

It creates a query builder over the model1 class , then joins it with your ManyToOne relation, filters via _id and then orders the result by the _test relation using the name field.

Aslo you need to declare in the @ManyToOne the target entity (https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional)

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=TheNameOfTheTestClass)
```